# Неправильно отображается размер базы данных

Tags: mysql

Есть сайт, который работает с базой данных MYSQL. Размер базы данных около 800МБ. Примерно раз в неделю получаю сообщение от хостера, что размер базы данных превышает 2ГБ. Проверяю в phpmyadmin размер базы - около 800МБ, т.е. как нужно. После запуска запроса на оптимизацию БД (OPTIMIZE TABLE ), размер отображается в панели снова правильно.

В чём может быть причина такого увеличения и как сделать так, чтобы всегда отображался правильный размер?

**Как определить таблицы, которые занимают на диске значительно больше места, чем имеются в них данные? я думаю, что ответ на этот вопрос может стать отправной точкой, чтобы определить причину этого увеличения и решить проблему.**

P.S. в базе данных есть часть данных, которые хранятся в таблицах InnoDB и часть в MyISAM... Может ли это быть причиной? как это исправить?

Comment: Размер БД следует смотреть в файловой системе, а не в пых-админе...

Comment: Я это понимаю, но вопрос в другом - как сделать так, чтобы определить, что есть причиной "раздувание" базы на диске более чем в 3 раза, при этом сами данные увеличиваются всего на несколько МБ... есть кэш в базе данных, но он всего максимум до 100мб. и как сделать, чтобы такого не было

Comment: Просто я регулярно получаю предупреждение, что запросы сайта будут заблокированы... и постоянно занимаюсь оптимизациями

Comment: [И как мы вам в этом вопросе можем помочь?](https://bash.im/quote/438821) У вас либо готовый движок (сказали б название что ли) или свой самописный (вам тогда лучше знать, что там внутри)

Comment: сайт на Drupal 7. На сайте установлен модуль, который  делает OPTIMIZE TABLE, но для меня важна причина, почему раздувается база на диске. Как определить таблицы, которые занимают больше места, чем реально имеют данных...

Comment: *почему раздувается база на диске* Такова схема хранения данных в файлах. И плюс отсутствие обслуживания, пока петух не клюнет. *Как определить таблицы, которые занимают больше места, чем реально имеют данных...* Все. Абсолютно все - иначе не может быть. А чтобы отыскать те, у коих процент оверхеда максимален, надо опять-таки смотреть в файловой системе.

Comment: *почему раздувается база на диске* Такова схема хранения данных в файлах. И плюс отсутствие обслуживания, пока петух не клюнет. *Как определить таблицы, которые занимают больше места, чем реально имеют данных...* Все. Абсолютно все - иначе не может быть. А чтобы отыскать те, у коих процент оверхеда максимален, надо опять-таки смотреть в файловой системе.